# Getting autocomplete of object-keys in flashbuilder

Tags: actionscript-3, object, autocomplete, key

Is it possible to get autocomplete-functionality on objects keys?

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.name = "AName";
obj.weight = "100";
```

When I type obj. -> i would like to see the keys(name,weight);

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash builder autocompletes only those properties/methods that are defined in the class (Defined might be a wrong word here, but I guess it is clear what I meant.) It does not autocomplete properties added in this way. As far as I know, this is not possible with flash builder.

Answer (score 0):

create a class :

```
package {
    public class NameWeightVO {
        public var name : String;
        public var weight : Number;

        public function NameWeightVO(pName : String = "", pWeight : Number = 0) {
        }
    }
}
```

then you can create a new NameWeightVO Object with autocomplete functionality:

```
var nameWeightVO : NameWeightVO = new NameWeightVO();
nameWeightVO.name = "name";
nameWeightVO.weight = 10;
```

Comment: judging from his question I am not too sure that this code snipped wont help him though